# Parsing named parameter values using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to come up with a script/alias that would quickly give me the list of processes run by an application. The parameters used to initiate the process by the application are **named** parameters and not **positional**

I need to extract the parameter values of **-u**, **-s** and **-svn**

```
$ ps -ef | grep pmdtm | grep -v grep

infa_adm 24581 31146  0 Oct24 ?        00:09:28 pmdtm -PR -gmh dhvifoapp03 
-gmp 6015 -guid ddcbd7ab-2ed0-4696-aea3-01573968b1bc -rst 300 
-s Address_Validator:wf_AddressValidator.s_m_AddressValidatorS 
-dn Session task instance [s_m_AddressValidatorS] -c pmserver.cfg 
-run 68_4262_654212_4_0_0_0_3263_77_2_2018_10_24___13_32_47_182 
-u Administrator -uns Native -crd rlVuBI4mUFi1V/7/jyrD6f9dMurwD9Yxddio6KDy/
zwlzM5rRDMeV766VoSBqb3Snjlvu849sTXlWpJ8WjzPomNOF4U87H7x5oy
JKbtxVg/vjR6gPwWwVSdEHvPjlpwSKPcuDx6glCbB1ksrvKCAzRsW1BTlP
GOfQbnd1ptnkO83iY14k4LUpJlx8+upBhwSxk9a0TPD44byO+/4Qhe7Mg== 
-svn Int01_dev -dmn Domain_dev 
-nma https://DHVIFOAPP03.RENTERS-CHOICE-INC.COM:6005 
-nmc w/Yt3IIMbmBQf+NnN1CAKmq5ab01nxZTJEA/YCf96Pb5zT9K9VFBO4+Nvqt
FuF8gzvqf/qHbw2tcXk4DnNP4m5vJvuEhxe9vQCN8pmpJytiZKV9Np7rBbapVzra
9TEOQVm9webRg8JZB70MQryVjQlGkJDpRs9cdOCXAu1aFhNE6LNF+
c5qhLdOz/vWCI3I2 -sid 3 
-hhn dhvifoapp04.renters-choice-inc.com -hpn 15555 
-hto 60 -rac 0 -SSL 
-rsn RAC_dev ServiceResilienceTimeout=300
```

I am able to extract it for a single field using the following command, but how do I get multiple values?

$ echo "List of running jobs ==> "; ps -ef | grep pmdtm | grep -v grep | awk -F"-s " "{print \$2}"|awk -F" " "{print \$1}"

```
List of running jobs ==>
Address_Validator:wf_AddressValidator.s_m_AddressValidatorS
```

Desired output =

```
List of running jobs ==>
Address_Validator:wf_AddressValidator.s_m_AddressValidatorS | Administrator | Int01_dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple "OR" expressions in `grep` with something like this:

```
grep -E "^-s|^-u|^-svn" < file.txt
```

The above will only print out the lines that start out with `-s`, `-u` or -`svn`.  Based on that, the following command does exactly what you want:

```
echo "List of running jobs ==> "  $(ps -ef | grep pmdtm | grep -v grep | grep -E "^-s|^-u|^-svn" | awk '{ print $2 " |" }')
```

When running your contents on the post with the above command, I get this output:

```
List of running jobs ==>  Address_Validator:wf_AddressValidator.s_m_AddressValidatorS | Administrator | Int01_dev |
```

You get a trailing `|` at the end, but you can trim that out separately.

**Updated:**

After your comment below, updated the command to do exactly what you need.

```
echo -e "List of running jobs ==> \n "  $(ps -ef | grep pmdtm | grep -v grep | awk 'BEGIN { RS = " -"} $1 ~ /^s$|^u$|^svn$/ { print $2,"|"}')
```

It does assume a couple of things:

- All the named parameters will have non-empty named parameters.  Otherwise, it will simply output a blank.
- That all the named parameters starts with a `-`, immediately followed by the parameter itself.

Comment: mJuarez - Thanks for the response. I played around with your suggestion, but it didn't give me output I was looking for. Please note that the example I had given in my original post is all in a single line; not multiple lines. I might have posted the question in multiple lines for ease of readability.

Comment: If this is the output of "ps -ef" : pmdtpm -s abc:def.ghi -u mjuarez -svn int01_dev

I would like the output :
abc:def.ghi | mjuarez | int01_dev

Comment: You never need more than a single instance of `awk`, `grep`, `sed`, or `cut` in the same pipeline... Separately, `grep`-ing through output of `ps` is nasty too -- use `pgrep`.

Comment: @TBT100 added to my answer so the command does exactly what you need.

Comment: @mjuarez - your updated solution worked; however, the awk command results appeared in a single line. I tried adding a new-line character in the print command, but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: @TBT100 updated the answer to print it out in two separate lines.